# inno setup call a function from a procedure

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I am trying to call a function from a procedure like so

```
//////////////////////////////////////////
//    Add Firewall Exception         //
/////////////////////////////////////////  
procedure CallAddPortException(Value: string);
begin
  SetFirewallPortException('MysqlPort'; NET_FW_PROTOCOL_TCP, 3311); '<= Error line
end;

//////////////////////////////////////////
//    Add Firewall Exception         //
/////////////////////////////////////////
procedure SetFirewallPortException(AppName: string; Protocol, Port: integer);
var
  FirewallObject: Variant;
  FirewallManager: Variant;
  FirewallProfile: Variant;
begin
  try
    FirewallObject := CreateOleObject('HNetCfg.FwOpenPort');
    FirewallObject.Name := AppName;
    FirewallObject.Scope := NET_FW_SCOPE_ALL;
    FirewallObject.IpVersion := NET_FW_IP_VERSION_ANY;
    FirewallObject.Protocol := Protocol;
    FirewallObject.Port := Port;
    FirewallObject.Enabled := True;
    FirewallManager := CreateOleObject('HNetCfg.FwMgr');
    FirewallProfile := FirewallManager.LocalPolicy.CurrentProfile;
    FirewallProfile.GloballyOpenPorts.Add(FirewallObject);
  except
  end;
end;
```

But I can't seem to get it to work. I am getting the following error

```
Unknown Identifier 'SetFirewallPortException'
```

Comment: Have you tried simply moving the definition of `SetFirewallPortException` before the definition of `CallAddPortException`?

Comment: Thanks, this work when moved the function

Comment: use forward definition. you have to replace ; with , in argument list.